# Nested SortedList

Tags: c#

I am a novice at C# and come from a PHP background where multidimensional arrays are a walk in the park.

How can one create a nested/multidimensional array with a SortedList in C#? I believe from reading that the SortedList is probably the most comparative in terms of PHP functionality. I've tried the following but it throws errors:

```
SortedList arr = new SortedList();
arr.Add("hello",new SortedList());
arr.hello.Add("world",new SortedList());
```

Comment: You probably want to use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Pro tip: c# is a **statically-typed** language. Your example could only ever work on untyped languages like PHP or JavaScript, or through the use of *dynamic*

Comment: Data structures are a much bigger subject in strongly typed languages. If you could be more clear about your exact requirements, we could guide you in the right direction. You should almost certainly be using generics. Non-generic `SortedList` has a bit of a Mauve Decade air about it these days.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You don't need an untyped language or `dynamic`.  You just need to use a non-generic collection, or use `object` as the generic argument.  There are of course better ways in which you could maintain static typing with such a model as well.

Comment: @Servy none of the options you are mentioning give you the possibility to access a member of the collection as a property, which is what I was referring to

Comment: So I would like to be able to access arr.hello.world which may be a string or another sorted list (or dictionary etc). It would need to be sortable by values too which is where I thought SortedList appeared to be best. PHP allows a much more fluid json type structure which I was seeking to replicate.

Comment: Again, C# is a statically typed language.  If you want to use `arr.hello.world`, you'll either a) use `dynamic` or b) create the classes to give you that structure.

Comment: If you prefer to use dynamics, make sure you catch a RunTimeBinderException. That being said, I would advise you to put up some sample data to be stored into a collection so that we can do better than shooting in the dark

Comment: "May be a string or another sorted list", looks like you want to use either dynamic or a new class.

Comment: @UKUser35 I urge you not to try to write PHP code in C#. Having worked professionally with a variety of languages with very different type systems, I've found that to be an elaborate method of self-torture, guaranteed to produce bad code at great cost. A hammer isn't a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

What about this.

```
class NestedSortedList<T> : SortedList<T, NestedSortedList<T>> { }
```

And testing..

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nestedSortedList = new NestedSortedList<string>();
            nestedSortedList.Add("1", new NestedSortedList<string>());
            nestedSortedList.Add("2", new NestedSortedList<string>());
            nestedSortedList.Add("3", new NestedSortedList<string>());

            nestedSortedList["1"].Add("11", new NestedSortedList<string>());
            nestedSortedList["2"].Add("21", new NestedSortedList<string>());
            nestedSortedList["2"].Add("22", new NestedSortedList<string>());

            foreach (var item in nestedSortedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                foreach (var value in item.Value.Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

This is the output

[image]

EDIT>>> Without creating NestedSortedList class

You may try the following, although you will have to deal with all those ugly casts.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sortedList = new SortedList();
            sortedList.Add("1", new SortedList());
            sortedList.Add("2", new SortedList());
            sortedList.Add("3", new SortedList());

            ((SortedList)sortedList["1"]).Add("11", new SortedList());
            ((SortedList)sortedList["2"]).Add("21", new SortedList());
            ((SortedList)sortedList["2"]).Add("22", new SortedList());

            foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in sortedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}",dictionaryEntry.Key,dictionaryEntry.Value);
                foreach (DictionaryEntry innerDictionaryEntry in (SortedList)dictionaryEntry.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner >>> Key: {0}, Value: {1}", innerDictionaryEntry.Key,
                        innerDictionaryEntry.Value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

And the output...

[image]

But please **beware**. Since non generic SortedList receives type **object** as key and value, this mean you could store whichever object you want but you will always need to cast them correctly in order to use them as its original type is intended to be used

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Would you not be able to do this without creating the Nested class first?

Comment: I have edited answer to show how to do it without creating Nested class

Comment: Also - I don't think I could add strings as well as lists here as the second parameter?

Answer (score -1):

Make a class

```
    public class MyList
    {
        string name { get; set;}
        List<MyList> children { get; set; }
    }
```

or

```
    public class MyList
    {

        SortedList<string, MyList> children = new SortedList<string, MyList>();
    }
```